# 301 redirect URL with query string, removing part of the beginning URL, keeping the full query at the end

Tags: .htaccess, query-string, http-status-code-301, rule

I'm trying to find a redirect that will remove part of a URL (in the middle), but leaves the query string in place at the end.

I can do this fine via a single url redirect, but there are hundreds of these urls so I'm trying to find a rule that might be able to do for all of them in one fell swoop, so i don't have to make one for each and any new ones will get redirected automatically.

I'm trying to remove 'search.php' from the urls, here is an example:

www.site.com/products/search.php?rPage=/items/listing/detail_handler.jsp?code=219592&units=Feet&item_id=2624472

to redirect to:
www.site.com/products/?rPage=/items/listing/detail_handler.jsp?code=219592&units=Feet&item_id=2624472

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Asking for clarification: You want the redirect to be done by Apache? By Nginx? By What?

And do you want an actual redirect or a rewrite?

Comment: With a rule in Apache's .htaccess file.  We were trying to do it with a rewrite rule, but to be honest I don't really care if it's a redirect or a rewrite so long as it works!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), the query string is passed through unchanged by default

```
RewriteRule products/search.php http://www.site.com/products/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: That has not worked. It says no match and would still go to: www.site.com/products/search.php as resulting URL.

Comment: What says "no match"? Do you have `RewriteEngine On` in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Yes, already have other redirects in place. Used a htaccess tester to try and debug as it didn't work.

Comment: Could you paste your full htaccess file? In isolation that rule should work fine.

Comment: I fixed it with: RedirectMatch 301 ^/products/search.php.*$ http://www.site.com/products/